# Codificación mensaje Cliente-Servidor JAVA con AES

Tags: java, codificación

Estoy probando una aplicación cliente-servidor muy básica en local, donde del lado del cliente se quiere introducir un texto en un input, y en un evento asignado a un botón, codificarlo y enviarlo al servidor utilizando un algoritmo AES. Y desde el lado del Servidor, decodificar el mensaje recibido y mostrarlo en un `JTextArea`.
El problema que tengo es que no me codifica el mensaje, imprimo en consola y pareciera que me devuelve un `hash()` lo que me gustaría saber es el porque de esto cuando lo que espero que me devuelva después del `dofinal()` es un cifrado.

LADO CLIENTE:

```
    JButton btnEnviar = new JButton("CODIFICA Y ENVIA");
    btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.18",9999);                  
                DataOutputStream flujo_salida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());
        
                //CIFRADO INPUT:
                KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");          
                kg.init(128);
                SecretKey clave= kg.generateKey();              
                Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave);                 
                byte texto_Plano[] = txtField.getText().getBytes();     //VALOR DEL JTEXTFIELD
                byte texto_Cifrado[] = c.doFinal(texto_Plano);              
                **System.out.println(texto_Cifrado.toString());  // ----> [B@6b9d9bc** 
         //FIN CIFRADO
            //ENVIO:    
                /*flujo_salida.writeUTF(texto_Cifrado.toString());                  
                flujo_salida.close();*/                 
                
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadPaddingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

CIFRADO EN OTRA CLASE:

```
  public class Cifrados {

    static String  texto = "La palabra crafia proviene del griego kryptos, "
        + "que significa oculto y graphia que significa escritura.";
    
    public Cifrados() {}

  public static void AES() {
        
    try {

    //ENCRIPTADO--------------------------------------------------------    
        KeyGenerator kGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");          
        kGenerator.init(128);
        SecretKey claveKey= kGenerator.generateKey();
    
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, claveKey);
                

        byte texto_Plano[] = texto.getBytes();          
        byte texto_Cifrado[] = cipher.doFinal(texto_Plano);     
    
        
        System.out.println(
            "TEXTO ORIGINAL: "+ texto+"\n\n"+
            "TEXTO CIFRADO: "+ new String(texto_Cifrado);                               
                                        
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Y si parece un `hash` no será que es un texto *cifrado*?

Comment: Si estás usando AES, estás generando un hash que no puedes recuperar. ¿Eso es lo que buscas? ¿Qué es para ti cifrado?

Comment: es probable que sea el resumen del mensaje codificado pero porque si yo implemento el mismo cifrado en otra clase si que me muestra la codificación? O de otra forma, como hago para que no me muestre el hash y si el mensaje codificado?

Comment: ¿Qué es un hash y qué es un mensaje codificado? Creo que estás confundido sobre lo que se supone que vas a obtener. Revisa cómo funciona AES

Comment: Sé lo que es una función hash(), quizás no me estoy explicando bien, o también puedo estar confundido, agregué una clase distinta donde si que puedo ver por consola el conjunto de bytes resultante de la codificación de un String, Porque en el primer caso me devuelve un hash() y en la otra clase donde se aplica el mismo algoritmo no?

Comment: No es lo mismo `new String(byteArray)` que `byteArray.toString()`. ¿Es eso? No nos estás diciendo claramente qué ves en cada caso y eso nos pone a adivinar, sólo estoy _adivinando_ a partir de un comentario que pusiste

Comment: Has adivinado bien. No es lo mismo new String(byteArray) que byteArray.toString(). De ahí mi error. Podrías reforzar esto así me queda mas claro?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que estás usando diferentes llaves para codificar y decodificar: `kGenerator.generateKey()`. [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) es un algoritmo simétrico. Esto quiere decir que tanto para cifrar como para descifrar se utiliza la misma llave.

Por lo tanto, lo que debes hacer es crear una llave y compartirla tanto en el cliente como en el servidor; y esa es la que debes usar en ambos lados.

Comment: El problema es que estaba queriendo ver el cifrado resultante con toString() y para lo que yo necesitaba debo utilizar new String(texto_Cifrado)

Comment: @Carlos Pero si usas llaves diferentes no puede funcionar.

Comment: Y como debería hacer para que del lado del servidor utilizar la misma llave?, como debo enviar esa key del cliente al servidor?

Comment: @Carlos pero no dices que lograste decodificar el mensaje correctamente? Para compartir las llaves puedes guardarlas en un archivo.